# accessing c++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary

Im trying to create a map for homework i declared it in the header and im trying to access it but i keep getting errors. im not sure whats wrong with the code. i implemented the code into the load function but i can't seem to get it to work in the get function if you could help thanks

this is the header file

```
class Movies {
    // data is private by default
    Movie *movies;
    int movieCnt;
    map<string,**string> Mymap;

public:
    Movies(string);
    int getMovieCount() const;
    const Movie * getMovie(string) const;
    ~Movies();

 private:
    void loadMovies(string);
    int getMovieHash(string) const;
};
```

this is the code

```
const Movie * Movies::getMovie(string mc) const {
    if(mc.length()==0)
        return NULL; // not found
    else
        return &(Mymap.find(mc));
}

Movies::~Movies() {delete[] movies; movies = NULL;}

void Movies::loadMovies(string fn) {
    ifstream iS(fn);  // technically should be c_str
    string s;
    getline(iS, s); // skip heading
    getline(iS, s);
    movieCnt=0;
    while(!iS.eof()) {
        Movie* m = new Movie(s);
        Mymap[(m->getTitle())] = *m;
        movieCnt++;
        getline(iS, s);
    }
    iS.close();
}
```

Comment: The declaration `map<string,**string> Mymap;` is not valid C++. Also, the errors you are getting, are they compiler errors (in which case you should include them)? Or are they runtime errors (in which case you should use a debugger to find them)?

Answer (score 1):

You have the pointer asterisks in the wrong place.  It should be like so:

```
 map<string,string**> Mymap;
```

or even more C++ like

```
 map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> Mymap;
```

Your `getMovie(string f)` function could be improved this way:

```
const Movie Movies::getMovie(string mc) const 
{
   if(mc.length() > 0)
   {
      auto it = Mymap.find(mc);
      if (it != Mymap.end())
         return *it; //by value
   }
   else
       throw std::runtime_error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of your map should be a `Movie` object.

```
map<string, Movie> Mymap;
```

Comment: Considering `Mymap[(m->getTitle())] = *m;`, it should be just a `Movie` object.

Comment: @MSalters  Correct.  Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific about your errors. What happens? In the meantime have a look at this:

```
const Movie * Movies::getMovie(string mc) const {
if(mc.length()==0)
    return NULL; // not found
else
    return &(Mymap.find(mc));
}
```

In `return &(Mymap.find(mc));` you are returning a pointer to a temporary object, this is very unlikely to work.
Try to return either the object itself,

```
const Movie Movies::getMovie(string mc) const {
if(mc.length()==0)
    return NULL; // not found
else
     std::map<string, string**>::const_iterator it = Mymap.find(mc);
     Movie m = it*;
     return m;
}
```

or an index to the entry and get it from the map using the index.

Comment: `std::map::find` returns an iterator to the element otherwise `std::map::end()`

Comment: for this part i keep getting a error that said no suitable conversion Movie m = Mymap.find(mc);

im not sure how to fix it . do i try to derefrence it somewhere else?

Comment: @TonyTheLion okay, I'll have a look at it